# Using another identifier to create a product if SKU isn't available in Magento 2.3

Tags: php, magento2

Is it possible to use another identifier if the SKU isn't available in Magento 2.3?

Our company daily imports products via a data feed from our primary supplier. It's all automated. We've setup cron jobs to receive the products via data feed every 2 hours, and sometimes some products come without a SKU. In that case we totally miss those products.

Is there any way we can set a condition where if the SKU isn't available, we create a new product based on another unique identifier such as AID code? This is another unique supplier code that comes with every product in the data feed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use any other identifier in the case on the SKU missing but make sure its unique to assign that in a new product.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, however I didn't understand what you meant by "make sure its unique to assign that in a new product." Could you please explain it?

Comment: I mean you can use the AID code for the SKU, as you mentioned its a unique supplier code.

Comment: Sure, got that.